# Why does display:none doesn't work on Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I cant get the display:none CSS property to work on Firefox:

```css
h1.hidden:hover {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a visible heading</h1>
<h1 class="hidden">This is a hidden heading</h1>
<p>Notice that the h1 element with display: none; does not take up any space.</p>
```

This simple code work on Chrome, Chromium, Edge, Safari, but not on firefox (V73.0), the second h1 does not disappear when i hover my mouse.

Comment: When the element is hidden, it _can not_ be “hovered” any more. Therefor, this rule stops applying, which makes the element visible again … which means it can be hovered again now, which triggers the whole cycle again and again and again …

Comment: @CBroe I Think the OP is saying the behavior between Firefox and the other browsers is different. In Chrome it flickers as it responds to the hover while in Firefox it doesn't change at all

Comment: Do you mean the element keep appearing et diseapearring so fast its not noticable? Or it just stay visible the all time?

Comment: It does disappear, but it reappears immediately so it is not noticeable.

Comment: @j08691 in Firefox I see the _cursor_ changing between normal cursor and text cursor, rapidly, when it is slightly moved over that element - so I guess Firefox is doing the same thing even faster, or does not update the display in between so that the effect would be noticable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element is no longer being hovered over when it is set to `display: none` since it no longer takes up space. The element is being hidden in Firefox, but it reappears immediately since it is no longer hoverable when not displayed.

#### Solution 1: Heading is not visible but takes up space

One solution to this problem would be to use `opacity` instead. That way the element still takes up space and can be hovered over.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
            h1.hidden:hover {
                opacity: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is a visible heading</h1>
        <h1 class="hidden">This is a hidden heading</h1>
        <p>Notice that the h1 element with display: none; does not take up any space.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### Solution 2: Heading does not take up space when hovering

If you want to make the `h1` no longer take up space, you can create a div in the background for detecting hovering and it must have an absolute or fixed position.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
            /* select size of hover area and allow elements to overlay */
            div.hide {
                border: 1px dashed #ccc; /* for previewing boundary (optional) */
                position: absolute; /* allow elements to overlay */
                height: 38px;
                width: 100%;
            }
            /* hide h1.hidden appearing directly after div.hide */
            div.hide:hover + h1.hidden {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is a visible heading</h1>
        <div class="hide"></div>
        <h1 class="hidden">This is a hidden heading</h1>
        <p>Notice that the h1 element with display: none; does not take up any space.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But with both your solutions, the element still takes up  space.

Comment: @bardamu I have added a third solution where the h1 does not take up extra space. The border can be removed from the div to make it fully invisible.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works but it's really intricate for something that just works out of the box on all other browsers!

Comment: @bardamu I made it a little less complicated by using `absolute` instead of `fixed`. You don't need to manually position the div if you use absolute positioning.

Comment: @bardamu I would not have expected the original code to work well in most browsers. An element that is not displayed should not be hoverable. I use Brave browser (Chromium-based) and I see constant flickering when I use the original.